# Count rectangular frames

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The grid is made up of $M \cdot N$ cells. The smallest cell formed is a square of unit area.

Now we are given a hoarding of area  $A$ units but there isn't any information on it's dimensions. It is also known that the hoarding will be rectangular in shape with integral edge length.

We need to find how many rectangular frames of different dimensions are possible with area $A$ units in the given grid.

Example : Let $M=3$ , $N=4$ and $A=6$ then answer is $7$.

How to do it for given $M,N$ and $A$ ? Can their be some direct formula ?

Comment: Are two frames considered different if they have the same dimensions but are positioned differently in the grid?  In your example, it seems frames can be $2$ by $3$ or $3$ by $2$.  But if you count frames in different positions as the same, I get two frames; but if I count them as different, I get $17$ frames.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @paw88789 Why 2 frames ? How 17 frames ?? I don't get how can you get 17 frames ?

Comment: $2$ by $3$, and $3$ by $2$.  But why $7$ frames?

Comment: I may not be understanding what a frame is.

Comment: @paw88789 No you were right. It was my typing error. The grid is actually 3*4 so there are 4 different 2x3, and 3 different 3x2 rectangles possible. Thus answer is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer: If we want to orient a rectangle of area $A$ as $j$ by $k$ (where $jk=A$) in an $m$ by $n$ grid, then there are $(m-j+1)\cdot(n-k+1)$ ways to position a $j$ by $k$ rectangle in the $m$ by $n$ grid.

So the total number of frames would be 
$$\sum_{\begin{matrix}jk=A\\j\le m,\; k\le n\end{matrix}}(m-j+1)(n-k+1)$$

Comment: Can their be more precise formula .Assume that A is very large of range 10^10

Comment: I don't see nice simplification right away.  One issue is that $A$ may be factorable in many ways, so just the number of terms in the sum is unpredictable.